# How can I get expression result?

Tags: c#, expression

I build an expression like below:

```
Expression left = Expression.Constant(5, typeof(int));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(6, typeof(int));
Expression result = Expression.Add(left,right);
```

So, can I get the real result about "5+6" via the expression result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to compile it as a `Func`:

```
Expression left = Expression.Constant(5, typeof(int));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(6, typeof(int));
Expression result = Expression.Add(left,right);

var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(result).Compile();
Console.WriteLine(compiled.Invoke());
```

[Expression tree docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-execute-expression-trees)

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/RKHWL85906)

Comment: See also [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-execute-expression-trees)

Comment: @Stephan added to the answer :) Thanks!